# How to Update child class when parent class changes in Enterprise Architect

Tags: oop, abstract-class, enterprise-architect

I want to make a class diagram in **Enterprise Architect ( Version 10.0 )** which implement an inheritance. I add an abstract class then create 3 class which implement abstract class.
Now if I make some change in abstract class, child classes doesn't change. (for example add another method to abstract class, but child class dose not have this method).
How can update(or refresh) a child class when parent class changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use my addin [EA-Matic](http://bellekens.com/ea-matic/) to do so.

EA-Matic catches the add-in events in Enterprise Architect and forwards them the built-in scripting environment.

This allows to create scripts with full blown add-in abilities, synchronizing overrides is just one of the possible applications.

One of the example scripts I wrote to demonstrate the add-in does exactly this: [Automatically synchronize overrides in Enterprise Architect with EA-Matic](http://bellekens.com/2015/02/10/automatically-synchronize-overrides-in-enterprise-architect-with-ea-matic/)

This example script uses the events `EA_OnContextItemChanged` to store the overrides of the selected operation

```
'Event Called when a new element is selected in the context. We use this operation to keep the id of the selected operation and a list of its overrides
'Because now is the only moment we are able to find it's overrides. Once changed we cannot find the overrides anymore because then they already
'have a different signature
function EA_OnContextItemChanged(GUID, ot)
    'we only want to do something when the selected element is an operation
    if ot = otMethod then
        'get the model
        dim model
        set model = getEAAddingFrameworkModel()
        'get the operation
        dim operation
        set operation = model.getOperationByGUID(GUID)
        'remember the operationID
        operationID = operation.id
        'remember the overrides
        set overrides = getOverrides(operation, model)
        Repository.WriteOutput "EA-Matic", overrides.Count & " overrides found for: " & operation.name,0
    end if
end function
```

and `EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified` to modify the overrides in case something changed.

```
'Event called when an element is changed. Unfortunately EA doesn't call it for an operation, only for the owner so we have to work with that.
function EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified(GUID, ot)
    'we only want to do something when the selected element is an operation
    if ot = otElement then
        'get the operation
        'Here we use the EA API object directly as most set methods are not implemented in EA Addin Framework
        dim wrappedOperation
        set wrappedOperation = Repository.GetMethodByID(operationID)
        dim modifiedElement
        set modifiedElement = Repository.GetElementByGuid(GUID)
        if not wrappedOperation is Nothing and not modifiedElement is Nothing then
            'check to be sure we have the same operation
            if modifiedElement.ElementID = wrappedOperation.ParentID AND overrides.Count > 0 then
                dim synchronizeYes
                synchronizeYes = MsgBox("Found " & overrides.Count & " override(s) for operation "& modifiedElement.Name & "." & wrappedOperation.Name & vbNewLine & "Synchronize?" _
                                        ,vbYesNo or vbQuestion or vbDefaultButton1, "Synchronize overrides?")
                if synchronizeYes = vbYes then
                    synchronizeOverrides wrappedOperation
                    'log to output

                    Repository.WriteOutput "EA-Matic", "Operation: " & wrappedOperation.name &" synchronized" ,0
                end if
                'reset operationID to avoid doing it all again
                operationID = 0
            end if
        end if
    end if
end function
```

In OnContextItemChanged it gets the overrides by first selecting all operations with the same signature from the model with a query.

```
'gets the overrides of the given operation by first getting all operations with the same signature and then checking if they are owned by a descendant
function getOverrides(operation, model)
    'first get all operations with the exact same signature
    dim overrideQuery
    overrideQuery = "select distinct op2.OperationID from (((t_operation op " & _
                    "inner join t_operation op2 on op2.[Name] = op.name) "& _
                    "left join t_operationparams opp on op.OperationID = opp.OperationID) "& _
                    "left join t_operationparams opp2 on opp2.OperationID = op2.OperationID) "& _
                    "where op.OperationID = "& operation.id &" "& _
                    "and op2.ea_guid <> op.ea_guid "& _
                    "and (op2.TYPE = op.Type OR (op2.TYPE is null AND op.Type is null)) "& _
                    "and (op2.Classifier = op.Classifier OR (op2.Classifier is null AND op.Classifier is null)) "& _
                    "and (opp.Name = opp2.Name OR (opp.Name is null AND opp2.Name is null)) "& _
                    "and (opp.TYPE = opp2.TYPE OR (opp.TYPE is null AND opp2.Type is null)) "& _
                    "and (opp.DEFAULT = opp2.DEFAULT OR (opp.DEFAULT is null AND opp2.DEFAULT is null)) "& _
                    "and (opp.Kind = opp2.Kind OR (opp.Kind is null AND opp2.Kind is null)) "& _
                    "and (opp.Classifier = opp2.Classifier OR (opp.Classifier is null AND opp2.Classifier is null)) "
    dim candidateOverrides
    set candidateOverrides = model.ToArrayList(model.getOperationsByQuery(overrideQuery))
    'then get the descendants of the owner
    dim descendants
    dim descendant
    'first find all elements that either inherit from the owner or realize it
    dim owner
    set owner = model.toObject(operation.owner)
    set descendants = getDescendants(owner, model)
    'then filter the candidates to only those of the descendants
    'loop operations backwards
    dim i
    for i = candidateOverrides.Count -1 to 0 step -1
        dim found
        found = false
        for each descendant in descendants
            if descendant.id = model.toObject(candidateOverrides(i).owner).id then
                'owner is a descendant, operation can stay
                found = true
                exit for
            end if
        next
        'remove operation from non descendants
        if not found then
            candidateOverrides.RemoveAt(i)
        end if
    next
    set getOverrides = candidateOverrides
end function
```

Then we its all the descendants of the owner of the operation (recursively) and filter the operations to only those owned by a descendant.

```
'gets all descendant of an element. That is all subclasses and classes that Realize the element.
'Works recursively to get them all.
function getDescendants(element, model)
    dim descendants
    dim getdescendantsQuery
    getdescendantsQuery = "select c.Start_Object_ID as Object_ID from (t_object o " _
                    & "inner join t_connector c on c.End_Object_ID = o.Object_ID) " _
                    & "where "_
                    & "(c.[Connector_Type] like 'Generali_ation' "_
                    & "or c.[Connector_Type] like 'Reali_ation' )"_
                    & "and o.Object_ID = " & element.id
    set descendants = model.toArrayList(model.getElementWrappersByQuery(getdescendantsQuery))
    'get the descendants descendants as well
    dim descendant
    dim descendantsChildren
    for each descendant in descendants
        if IsEmpty(descendantsChildren) then
            set descendantsChildren = getDescendants(descendant, model)
        else
            descendantsChildren.AddRange(getDescendants(descendant, model))
        end if
    next
    'add the descendantsChildren to the descendants
    if not IsEmpty(descendantsChildren) then
        if  descendantsChildren.Count > 0 then
            descendants.AddRange(descendantsChildren)
        end if
    end if
    set getDescendants = descendants
end function
```

Finally it synchronizes the operations using the following functions

```
'Synchronizes the operation with it's overrides
function synchronizeOverrides(wrappedOperation)
    dim override
    for each override in overrides
        dim wrappedOverride
        set wrappedOverride = override.WrappedOperation
        'synchronize the operation with the override
        synchronizeOperation wrappedOperation, wrappedOverride
        'tell EA something might have changed
        Repository.AdviseElementChange wrappedOverride.ParentID
    next
end function

'Synchronizes the operation with the given override
function synchronizeOperation(wrappedOperation, wrappedOverride)
    dim update
    update = false
    'check name
    if wrappedOverride.Name <> wrappedOperation.Name then
        wrappedOverride.Name = wrappedOperation.Name
        update = true
    end if
    'check return type
    if wrappedOverride.ReturnType <> wrappedOperation.ReturnType then
        wrappedOverride.ReturnType = wrappedOperation.ReturnType
        update = true
    end if
    'check return classifier
    if wrappedOverride.ReturnType <> wrappedOperation.ReturnType then
        wrappedOverride.ReturnType = wrappedOperation.ReturnType
        update = true
    end if
    if update then
        wrappedOverride.Update
    end if
    'check parameters
    synchronizeParameters wrappedOperation, wrappedOverride
end function

'Synchronizes the parameters of the given operatin with that of the overrride
function synchronizeParameters(wrappedOperation, wrappedOverride)
    'first make sure they both have the same number of parameters
    if wrappedOverride.Parameters.Count < wrappedOperation.Parameters.Count then
        'add parameters as required
        dim i
        for i = 0 to wrappedOperation.Parameters.Count - wrappedOverride.Parameters.Count -1
            dim newParameter
            set newParameter = wrappedOverride.Parameters.AddNew("parameter" & i,"")
            newParameter.Update
        next
        wrappedOverride.Parameters.Refresh
    elseif wrappedOverride.Parameters.Count > wrappedOperation.Parameters.Count then
        'remove parameters as required
        for i = wrappedOverride.Parameters.Count -1 to wrappedOperation.Parameters.Count step -1
            wrappedOverride.Parameters.DeleteAt i,false
        next
        wrappedOverride.Parameters.Refresh
    end if
    'make parameters equal
    dim wrappedParameter
    dim overriddenParameter
    dim j
    for j = 0 to wrappedOperation.Parameters.Count -1
        dim parameterUpdated
        parameterUpdated = false
        set wrappedParameter = wrappedOperation.Parameters.GetAt(j)
        set overriddenParameter = wrappedOverride.Parameters.GetAt(j)
        'name
        if overriddenParameter.Name <> wrappedParameter.Name then
            overriddenParameter.Name = wrappedParameter.Name
            parameterUpdated = true
        end if
        'type
        if overriddenParameter.Type <> wrappedParameter.Type then
            overriddenParameter.Type = wrappedParameter.Type
            parameterUpdated = true
        end if
        'default
        if overriddenParameter.Default <> wrappedParameter.Default then
            overriddenParameter.Default = wrappedParameter.Default
            parameterUpdated = true
        end if
        'kind
        if overriddenParameter.Kind <> wrappedParameter.Kind then
            overriddenParameter.Kind = wrappedParameter.Kind
            parameterUpdated = true
        end if
        'classifier
        if overriddenParameter.ClassifierID <> wrappedParameter.ClassifierID then
            overriddenParameter.ClassifierID = wrappedParameter.ClassifierID
            parameterUpdated = true
        end if
        'update the parameter if it was changed
        if parameterUpdated then
            overriddenParameter.Update
        end if
    next
end function
```

Comment: Please explain your add-on here.

Comment: @kleopatra I added (a lot) more detail to my answer on your request.

Answer (score 4):

Select the class and press `Ctrl + Shift + o` to refresh.  However this doesn't perform full refresh, so you will need to remove older versions of operations etc, but EA will display the override methods dialog.

Answer (score 1):

When you tell EA to override or implement an operation in a base class or interface, it creates a copy of the operation in the child class. This copy has no reference to the original base class / interface, and subsequent changes are not reflected in the child.

If you draw a realization to an interface and select not to override any operations, EA will generate code for them as you'd expect, but it doesn't do that for abstract classes - even if the child is a leaf.

You can always modify the code generation templates (Tools - Source Code Generation Templates). They're a bit tricky to get your head around the first time, but you'll soon get the hang of it.

Comment: There is no way to update child class? (except delete then redraw)